# awk not working when used with /bin/bash -c

Tags: bash, awk, sh

This correctly prints `test`

```
$ echo 'this is a test' | awk '{print $4}'
test
```

While using this command inside `/bin/bash -c` does not work

```
/bin/bash -c "echo 'this is a test' | awk '{print $4}'"
this is a test
```

How can I get awk to work correctly when using with `/bin/bash -c`?

Comment: Yes: `/bin/bash -c "echo 'this is a test' | awk '{print \$4}'"`

Comment: Note: You need to escape the `$`. Ill search for a duplicate ;)

Comment: @anubhava Phh, some sort of dyslexia? 'this' !== 'test'.... Thx for the wake up call.

Comment: Also that dupe only talks about `bash -c` but OP is asking about `awk` as well and that dupe doesn't explain why OP is getting full line in output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$4` is expended by shell since you have double quoted command string.

You can check trace output by adding `-x` in `bash` command line:

```sh
bash -xc "echo 'this is a test' | awk '{print $4}'"
+ echo 'this is a test'
+ awk '{print }'
this is a test
```

Since `$4` expands to an empty string it effectively runs `awk '{print }'` and thus complete line is printed in output.

To fix this, you should be using an escaped `$` to avoid this expansion:

```sh
bash -c "echo 'this is a test' | awk '{print \$4}'"
test
```